# Unable to run Node.js http-server even though it's installed globally

Tags: node.js

If I install [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) globally and then run it:

```
npm install http-server -g

http-server
```

I get the error:

```
'http-server' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How can I fix that? It works on my other user account but on this separate account, which I need to be on, I can't seem to get it working.

Comment: How was node.js installed? Which OS? What program are you using to run your shell/CLI? It's likely the user account does not have the NODE_PATH environment variable properly set for your CLI app or OS user profile.

Comment: @SteveHynding IIIRC I think Node was installed on my other account and when I checked install on this account it was working, or else I installed it normally on this account. OS: Windows 10. I'm using command prompt, running as admin. Edit: Googled how to change NODE_PATH but everything related to that seems to be referring to Unix systems.

Comment: Not a Windows 10 user, but older windows had a place to set Environment Variables through the settings UI. I didn't think it was based on user profiles, though. It's been a while and a differently/better built Windows.